# Simple, easy to understand way to soften edges?

Tags: shaders, edges

I come from Maya, I'm used to just selecting the edges or faces you want to be soft or sharp and clicking a button that says "harden edge" or "soften edge." Is there a way to do this in Blender? I can't find a reliable way of doing it online. I don't want to have to add modifiers, or only selecting faces instead of edges, or select "auto smooth" or anything like that. I just want it nice and simple: select the edges you want to look soft and soften them, in 2 clicks or less, no ifs or buts. I refuse to watch any YouTube tutorial that's longer than 30 seconds on this.

Edit: "Mark sharp" doesn't work for me, it just turns the edges cyan in edit mode and nothing else. And I don't want anyone to tell me I have to use "split edge" without explaining what that means, I don't wanna add vertices to my mesh and that shouldn't have to happen. I'm terribly confused.

Edit: Ultimately what I want is control, I want to be able to smooth and sharpen any edge I want, with no ifs or buts. The only way to do that is if Blender let's you sharpen and smooth any edge you select, but as far as I'm able to figure out on the internet and from a friend who uses Blender so far is that that's not possible. Now I want to understand why it isn't possible.

Comment: I guess Shade Smooth + Auto-Smooth + ctrl E > Mark Sharp is the fastest way, why are you not happy with it?

Comment: You can use mark sharp, but it has to be used in combination with either auto smooth or the edge split modifier. Blender is not Maya, certain aspects work differently. You can also set smooth or flat shading for individual faces by selecting them in edit mode and using *Face > Shade Smooth* or *Face > Shade Flat*.

Comment: I'd like to be able to soften edges that have been sharpened with auto-smooth, without having to soften the entire mesh. If that's not possible, I'd like to understand why, is Maya just lying to me and pretending it's possible for example? I don't mean that in an annoyed way, if I've been living a lie the past 3 years I just wanna know about it.

Comment: @ Derek lol yeah living a lie ;)